# Prove that $\bigcup_{i=k}^{k+m-1} R^i$ is idempotent, where $k,m$ are the index and period of $R$.

Tags: relations, semigroups

Let $R$ be a binary relation on $[n]$.  Let $k$ be the index of $R$, i.e., the smallest positive integer such that $R^k = R^{k+m}$ for some $m \geq 1$.  Let $m$ be the period of $R$, i.e., the smallest positive integer satisfying this equation.  Then the relations $R^k,R^{k+1},R^{k+2},\ldots ,R^{k+m-1}$ form a cyclic group.

In David Rosenblatt, "On the graphs of finite idempotent Boolean relation matrices", it is stated without proof that  $\bigcup_{i=k}^{k+m-1} R^i$ is idempotent.

I can see that this union is transitive because it is the transitive closure of a generator of the cyclic group.

I cannot prove that the union is dense, i.e., if $(x,y)$ is in the union then there is a $z$ such that $(x,z)$ and $(z,y)$ are also in the union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually true in any [(additively) idempotent semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring) $S$. Let $r \in S$ be such that $r^k = r^{k+m}$. As you pointed out, $G = \{r^k, \ldots, r^{k+m} \}$ is a cyclic group with identity $e$. In particular, for every $n \geqslant 0$, $r^{k+n} \in G$. It follows that
$$
\sum_{i=k}^{k+m-1} r^i = \sum_{x \in G} x
$$
is idempotent since
$$
\bigl(\sum_{x \in G} x\bigr)\bigl(\sum_{y \in G} y\bigr) = 
\sum_{x \in G}xe + \sum_{x \in G}\sum_{y \in G - \{e\}} xy = \sum_{x \in G} x
$$

Comment: @ J. E. Pin   Thanks.  I do not understand  why the last equality holds.

Comment: Because the double sum is a sum of some elements of $G$, which is "absorbed" by the sum of all elements of $G$.